# Advanced integration, how to integrate 1/polynomial ? Thanks

Tags: integration

I have been trying to integrate a function with a polynomial as the denominator.

i.e, how would I go about integrating

$$\frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}.$$

Any help at all with this would be much appreciated, thanks a lot :)

ps The polynomial has NO real roots 
$${}{}$$

Comment: Parentheses, please.  Presumably you mean to integrate ${1}/(ax^2+bx+c)$

Comment: This should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fractions_in_integration

Comment: Lookup "partial fraction decomposition".

Comment: Ross Millikan I assumed that would be clear if you read the title and put two and two together

Comment: @Justin The notation is important. $1/ax^2+bx+c\ne 1/(ax^2+bx+c)$.

Comment: gawdddddd okay sorry

Answer (score 12):

The details depend on $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Assume $a\ne 0$. If there are two distinct real roots, use partial fractions.

If there are two identical real roots, we are basically integrating $\dfrac{1}{u^2}$.

If there are no real roots, complete the square. With the right substitution, you basically end up integrating $\dfrac{1}{1+u^2}$, and get an $\arctan$.

For polynomials of higher degree, factor as a product of linear terms and/or quadratics with no real roots. (In principle this can be done. In practice, it may be very unpleasant).

Then using partial fractions and substitutions you end up with integrals of $\dfrac{1}{u^{n}}$, and/or $\dfrac{u}{(1+u^2)^{n}}$ and/or $\dfrac{1}{(1+u^2)^{n}}$. All of these are doable.

**Added:** It turns out the OP was interested in the irreducible case. Will write a bit on that, because I want to advocate a procedure **slightly** different from the standard one. Assume that $a$ is positive.

Rewrite $\dfrac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}$ as 
$\dfrac{4a}{4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac}$, and then, completing the square, as $\dfrac{4a}{(2ax+b)^2+4ac-b^2}$.

Note that $4ac-b^2$ is positive. Call it $k^2$, with $k$ positive.

Make the change of variable $2ax+b=ku$. Substitute. There is some cancellation, and we end up integrating $\dfrac{2}{k}\dfrac{1}{1+u^2}.$

I would suggest going through this *procedure* in any individual case. As an example, with $\dfrac{1}{x^2+x+1}$ we write $\dfrac{4}{4x^2+4x+4}$, then $\dfrac{4}{(2x+1)^2+3}$, make the change of variable $2x+1=\sqrt{3} u$.

**Another addition:** The OP has expressed a wish to see the particular problem $\int\frac{dx}{x^2+10x+61}$.  The numbers here are particularly simple, designed for the "standard" style, so we will do it that way.  Also, we will use more steps than necessary.

First we **complete the square**. We get $x^2+10x+61=(x+5)^2-25+61=(x+5)+36$.
Now let $u=x+5$. Then $du=dx$ and
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+10x+61}\int \frac{dx}{(x+5)^2+36}=\int\frac{du}{u^2+36}.$$

Now maybe think: it would be nice if we had $u^2=36w^2$, because the $36$ could then "come out." So let $u=6w$. Then $du=6\,dw$, and we get
$$\int\frac{du}{u^2+36}=\int \frac{6\,dw}{36w^2+36}=\int\frac{1}{6}\frac{dw}{w^2+1}=\frac{1}{6}\arctan(w) +C.$$
Finally, we undo our substitution. We have $w=\frac{u}{6}=\frac{x+5}{6}$.

Comment: sorry I should have said that the quotient in particular had no real roots, so it would be the second instance with arctan, thank you very much andre Nicolas, this was a great help

Comment: also I completed the square now and I am still stuck, sorry it is probably obvious but where do I go from there?

Comment: I added stuff on that, in a style slightly different and I think easier than the usual one. If I had known your numbers, would have used those.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x^2+10x+61}$ please help

Comment: @Justin: I will do it in a few minutes, probably using the standard style, since the numbers are designed for that. It will be added to the main poast, easier to type there.

Comment: Thank you so much andre, you complete genius legend!

Answer (score 5):

If $a=0$, then
$$I = \int \dfrac{dx}{bx+c} = \dfrac1b \log (\vert bx+c \vert) + \text{constant}$$
$$I = \int \dfrac{dx}{ax^2 + bx + c} = \dfrac1a \int\dfrac{dx}{\left(x + \dfrac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{c}a- \dfrac{b^2}{4a^2} \right)}$$
If $b^2 < 4ac$, then recall that
$$\int \dfrac{dt}{t^2 + a^2} = \dfrac1a\arctan \left(\dfrac{t}a \right) + \text{constant}$$
Hence, if $b^2 < 4ac$, then
$$I = \dfrac2{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}} \arctan \left( \dfrac{2ax + b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}} \right) + \text{constant}$$
If $b^2 = 4ac$, then
$$I =\dfrac1a \dfrac{-1}{\left(x + \dfrac{b}{2a}\right)} + \text{constant} = - \dfrac2{2ax+b} + \text{constant}$$
If $b^2 > 4ac$, then
$$I = \dfrac1a \int\dfrac{dx}{\left(x + \dfrac{b}{2a}\right)^2 - \sqrt{\left( \dfrac{b^2}{4a^2} -\dfrac{c}a\right)}^2}$$
Now $$\int \dfrac{dt}{t^2 - k^2} = \dfrac1{2k} \left(\int \dfrac{dt}{t-k} - \int \dfrac{dt}{t+k} \right) = \dfrac1{2k} \log \left(\left \vert \dfrac{t-k}{t+k} \right \vert \right) + \text{constant}$$
Hence, if $b^2 > 4ac$, then
$$I = \dfrac1{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}} \log \left(\left \vert \dfrac{2ax + b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2ax + b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}} \right \vert \right) + \text{constant}$$

Comment: Marvis, thanks a lot my answer will involve arctan, once I complete the square, where do I go from there? Thanks again